# Como posso traduzir «stack overflow»?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Está a decorrer uma [discussão no SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5126/7210) para saber qual a melhor tradução de *[stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)* tendo em conta a sua definição na área da informática.

de Wikipedia:

> In software, a **stack overflow** occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds
>   the stack bound. The call stack may consist of a limited amount of
>   address space, often determined at the start of the program. The size
>   of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming
>   language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of
>   available memory. When a program attempts to use more space than is
>   available on the call stack (that is, when it attempts to access
>   memory beyond the call stack's bounds, which is essentially a buffer
>   overflow), the stack is said to overflow, typically resulting in a
>   program crash.

Qual seria então a tradução de *stack overflow*?

Comment: Sendo preciosista, o próprio termo _stack overflow_ não é muito exato porque quando o _buffer overflow_ está prestes a ocorrer o sistema dispara uma _segmentation fault_ e não deixa a memória ser invadida. Estaria mais para um _stack overflow attempt_ ou _stack limit reached_. Mas isto é só um parêntese, pois acredito que devemos nos ater ao termo em inglês que todos conhecem e adotam. A meu ver, a tradução mais exata seria "transbordo de pilha", a não ser que seja constatado que existe um conjunto significativo de referências em português (inclusive livros) usando o termo "estouro".

Comment: em pt-BR é estouro de pilha, que significa que o ponteiro estourou o limite da pilha (de empilhamento); transbordo de pilha, se fosse usado, seria transbordamento da pilha para não ser confundido com baldeação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Transbordo de pilha

Isto seria talvez uma tradução mais literal e específica do que `estouro de pilha`.

Poderia haver um "estouro" relacionado com a pilha que tivesse outras razões que não o transbordar por adicionar coisas quando ela já está cheia.

Mas «estouro de pilha» parece ser mais idiomático, na comunidade brasileira.

Comment: Quais outras razões poderiam ser?

Comment: @Piovezan poderia uma [stack buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) ser também um estouro de pilha?

Comment: Pela tradução literal do termo em inglês, sim. Realmente é uma outra razão possível. Nesse caso o _overflow_ realmente chega a ocorrer e não é apenas uma tentativa. Se eu não tivesse que me ater ao uso corrente do termo, eu pessoalmente traduziria "stack buffer overflow" como "invasão de pilha", porque é isso que realmente está ocorrendo.

Comment: e _buffer overflow_, _signed integer overflow_? Usarias também _transbordo_? Faz sentido fazer transbordar um inteiro?

Comment: Sim, @Artefacto , **se** tivesse de traduzir isso (em Portugal não traduzimos esses termos técnicos) então acho que usaria transbordo na mesma. O meu maior problema é com a palavra relacionada *underflow* - não tenho tradução para essa.

Answer (score 4):

Eu acho que a tradução direta é a melhor opção neste caso. A razão é: o termo em Inglês foi usado na computação por causa da imagem que cria. Para os que falam Inglês bem, se alguém falar "stack overflow" você pode ver uma **pilha** ficando muito grande e **transbordando**. E também as palavras *stack* e *overflow* foram "criadas" no Inglês sem o propósito de serem usadas para computação, então eu acho que a tradução tem que pegar a mesma rota. Até em Inglês você teria que explicar o significado da frase, se estivesse falando com alguém que não é familiar com linguagem de programador.

Comment: Uma pilha [real] de coisas não transborda. Numa pilha empilham-se coisas, e quando se empilham demasiadas ela tomba (*it topples*). Mas com o resto concordo.

Comment: Quando algo ultrapassa um limite, ela estoura o limite, Assim o termo usado é o estouro de pilha. E a pilha é um modelo que não é realmente físico. Pode-se então dar vários formatos a este modelo em computação, incluindo as matrizes e vetores que não são representações de empilhamento.